# Opticks 4.11.0 (Ubuntu 64bit) - unable to load TIFF file

Tags: remote-sensing, linux, 64bit, opticks

I am trying Opticks 4.11.0-1 - have official release [opticks_4.11.0-1_amd64.deb](http://opticks.org/confluence/display/opticks/Downloading+Opticks+4.11.X...?download_url=/opticks/4.11.0/opticks_4.11.0-1_amd64.deb) but unlike in Windows I am totally unable to load Landsat 7 TIFF files. In Windows I can do this using auto importer. In linux it reports The dataset is empty" although I am able to load the same file on windows machine without problem.

The package looks to be OK in Muon Package Manager (so not corrupted), gdal is installed (I also have QGIS) and Opticks do not show any error message during startup.

Do you have any idea what could be problem?

thanks

Comment: Needs the Tiff Package https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tiff

Comment: strange - have installed: libtiff-opengl, libtiff-tools, python-libtiff, libtiff5, libtiffxx5 and also 32bit version of libtiff5 but problem is still there.Libgeotiff2 also installed...

Comment: What Version of Ubuntu? 14.04 LTS or Ubuntu LTS 12.04?

Comment: 14.04 LTS - it is Kubuntu but DE should have no influence on this (hope so).

Comment: which version of qgis? Source of QGIS? Version of gdal?

Comment: Hi, I am using the repository http://qgis.org/debian trusty main so I have Valmiera - but do not have access to that PC now, so cannot say exact versions - will check later.

Comment: So, QGIS is 2.2.0-3+trusty1, GDAL is gdal-bin, version 1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1.Also have libgdal1h, same version as gdal-bin.